# How to specify width and height of my object JAVA

Tags: java, processing

So i am trying to add collision detection for a little game i am creating and i am specifying the width and height of my defender class however i am unable to do so. My code below gives me an error saying the global variable width and height do not exist

```
class Defender
{
  int x,y;

  Defender(int x, int y)
  {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
  }

  void render()
  {
    //draw a defender
 fill(255,0,0);
 rect(x,y,50,20);
 triangle(x+50,y,x+50,y+20,x+60,y+10);
 fill(0,0,100);
 rect(x,y-10,20,10);
  }


  boolean collision()
  {
   color detectedColour;
   for (int i=y; i<y+ Defender.height; i++) {
     detectedColour = get(x + Defender.width, i);
     if (detectedColour == Alien1) {
       return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare height and width? The compiler is not wrong

Comment: You've declared local variables x and y but no static variables height and width....

Comment: Please respect the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts. `width` and `height` are built in global variables in processing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to access the variables **statically** when they do not exist in the class. Create class members that represent the width and height of the defender.

```java
class Defender {

    private final int x;

    private final int y;

    private final int width;

    private final int height;

    public Defender(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    // getters
}
```

```java
Defender defender = new Defender(0, 0, 1, 1);

int width = defender.width;

int height = defender.height;
```

Comment: but this will constraint all the defenders to have same width & height... I recommend to @Zubair Ali to learn more about OOP

Comment: Yeah I completely agree. Let me update to include a more OO approach.